# Функция и куча

Tags: память, c++

Вопрос. Есть такой вот код, к примеру

```
    void getpath(char *argv)
    {
     char * buffer = new char[255];
     return buffer;
    }
```

После выхода из функции, будет ли вызвана delete[] buffer автоматически?

Comment: Нет, нет и еще раз нет. Если забыть про delete, то это прямой путь к утечке памяти.

Кстати, почему функция объявлена как ничего не возвращающая а в ней имеется return buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Теоретически - нет. Память была занята под строку и нигде в функции не освобождалась. Хотя область видимости переменной "buffer" - это функция "getpath", но это не означает, что после завершения работы функции все использованные ею ячейки памяти освободятся. Поэтому, вызывайте  delete[] buffer вручную.

Comment: Тут не место слову **теоретически.** На каждый вызов `new` должен быть один вызов `delete` и никто другой, кроме вас, не будет освобождать выделенную память.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нет. Но если Вы хотите обеспечивать автоматическое разрушение объекта при выходе из области видимости указателя, то советую смотреть в сторону `boost::scoped_ptr<T>`. Помимо boost, реализация умных указателей присутствует в Qt. Также они вошли в свежий стандарт C++11 (`const std::unique_ptr<T>`).

Comment: Ну, кроме scoped_ptr еще куча других умных указателей имеется.

Comment: а ну-ка к примеру

Comment: @pol500 `shared_ptr`, `shared_array`, `weak_ptr`, `intrusive_ptr` и прочие радости жизни.

Comment: И светлой памяти auto_ptr

Comment: А, еще забыли прелестные вещи вроде `СComPtr` и `CComQIPtr`.

Comment: Я, кстати, имел в виду именно `const std::unique_ptr<T>` как точный аналог `boost::scoped_ptr<T>` с запретом семантики переноса. Ну да ладно :)

Comment: @northerner Ну если уж на то пошло, то аналогия-то не до конца точная, поскольку `scoped_ptr` не умеет `custom deleter'ы`. Но вообще да, можно вернуть `const`)

Comment: Кстати говоря, несколько удивило вот это: [**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019512/c0x-unique-ptr-replaces-scoped-ptr-taking-ownership**][1]

1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019512/c0x-unique-ptr-replaces-scoped-ptr-taking-ownership